# Win 2008 R2: New router installed by ISP, DHCP is working, but "old" shares are inacessable

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp

On our small Windows 2008 R2 Server based network (8 x Win7 clients):

During an internet upgrade, our internal IP address ranges needed to be changed from 192.168.ZERO.xxx to 192.168.ONE.xxx. All IP internal client addresses are assigned by the ISP router via DHCP.

The clients readily accepted the new DHCP configuration and all workstations can access the internet. All looks OK via ipconfig /all.

However, on all clients, "Shares" no longer function. Looking for `\\PC-SALES` results in "Network path not found" ... However `\\192.168.1.PC-SALES-NEWIPADDRESS` shows the share fully functional as expected.

How can I "refresh" the clients to accept the new IP range but keeping the "old" share names??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the new DHCP server give to the clients for DNS configuration?

They're no longer able to resolve DNS for internal systems, which indicates that they were once pointing to the Windows server for DNS and are now pointing to the new ISP router.

Comment: Duh!  Of course!   dns is set via DHCP to the isp dns! Thank you for your answer - it has pointed me in the right direction! _ I wish I could accept the answer from anthonysomerset too ... but an upvote will have to suffice!

Answer (score 2):

is the new router set to give the dns server IP as the one for your networks dns server (most likely your windows server)

if not, that is exactly why its not working for you, you need to change that setting on your new router so that computers know to look at your server for dns and not the router itself

Comment: Please see comment to Shane Madden above ... you are right - I am sorry I could not give you both "accepted"